# Check if string is X509Store path or PFX file

Tags: powershell, x509certificate

I need to check if a string is a certificate store (eg. `"Cert:\CurrentUser\My"`) or a pfx file path (eg. `"D:\\PFXfiles\self-signed.pfx"`)

Which method is better to use and why? What are the cons/pros for each? Is there a better method?
Method 1:

```
if ($certLocation.ToUpper().Contains(".PFX"))
{
    #it's a .pfx file
}
else
{
    #it's a cert store
}
```

Method 2:

```
if ((Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $certLocation).Provider.Name -eq "FileSystem")
{
    #it's a .pfx file
}
elseif ((Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $certLocation).Provider.Name -eq "Certificate"
{
    #it's a cert store
}
```

Comment: Are those the only two options? What do you want to do if neither is correct? Usually the answer is to assume one and try the other if you run into an error, is there a reason that won't work?

Comment: no these were the 2 given, I'm keen to know if there is a better option.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to not assume and not run into the error. Exceptions are expensive.

Comment: Exceptions are expensive in certain performance sensitive situations. Powershell scripts are often light enough to not care. In either case I was thinking about non-exception based checks.

Comment: In what sense is trusting a file name/extension better than actually checking properties of a file? I would extend that to actually trying to load the file as a pfx instead of assuming it was one because it was a real file (but that might not be necessary in this context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `Split-Path`:

```psh
switch ((Split-Path $certLocation -Qualifier)) {
  'cert:' { 'cert store' }
  'c:'    { 'file path' }
  default { Write-Error "invalid provider: $_" }
}
```

Check the extension inside the 'file path' script block if required.

Comment: why is this better than the other options?

Comment: Because it distinguishes paths by their distinguishing feature. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: is ".pfx" not a distinguishable feature for a pfx file name? This is 4 lines of code, but checking if the string has ".pfx" is one line of code.

Comment: +1 This is the most elegant way to distinguish between a file and cert store. As for the file extension, you will have to check that anyway, if you intend to use the certificate. In real life there are a whole bunch of different extensions for certificates (.pfx, .cer, .pem) and even then you will have to check the contents to verify it is actually a certificate in the right format.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave A path ending with `.pfx` doesn't automatically mean that the path is in the file system (for instance `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pfx`). The PSDrive is what distinguishes between paths from different providers.

Answer (score 0):

you should see [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) of file , I recommend to you use `file` command exist in linux and the programmer provide for windows see this [link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) 
see my example

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>file.exe c:\Users\soheil\Desktop\1.pfx
c:\Users\soheil\Desktop\1.pfx; data

C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>file.exe c:\Users\soheil\Desktop\2.pfx
c:\Users\soheil\Desktop\2.pfx; empty
```

or like this

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>file.exe c:\a.txt
c:\a.txt; UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) English text, with very long lines, with CRLF
 line terminators
```

first 1.pfx i create self sign with IIS
second 2.pfx i rename txt file to 2.pfx 
if you want exactly understand what file is you should use `file` command for see magic number

Answer (score 0):

To me, testing the string would be better because it's more efficient to just manipulate the string vs resolving the path, creating another object and then reading a property of on that object, but in reality it's not going to change anything. I'd do it a little differently though.

```
if ($certLocation.Split(":")[0] -like "cert") { 
    #it's a cert store
}
else {
    #it's a pfx
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll chime in... If you are testing a string to see where the path lies use the Resolve-Path cmdlet, and select the Provider property.

```
$StringPath = "Cert:\CurrentUser\my","C:\Temp\fakecert.pfx"

Switch($StringPath){
    {(Resolve-Path $_|Select -Expand Provider).tostring() -eq "Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate"} {"$_ is in the Certificate Store";continue}
    {(Resolve-Path $_|Select -Expand Provider).tostring() -eq "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem"} {"$_ is in the File System"}
}

Cert:\CurrentUser\my is in the Certificate Store
C:\Temp\fakecert.pfx is in the File System
```

That way PowerShell will tell you who it used to resolve the path. This will throw errors if you provide invalid paths, but should give you accurate info as to where items are stored. Error catching could be added to catch invalid paths, but that's up to you.